# Ordered repetitions of timestamp grouped date in posgresql - sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2020-07-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2020-06-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2020-05-02', '2020-04-28 02:28:41'),
       ('LMUS01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-01 06:29:53'),
       ('LMUS01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-02 07:30:59'),   
       ('LMUS01', '2020-02-02', '2020-01-31 06:58:18')
```

I want to query this table and add a column which indicates an order of the "date" (no matter the time) of `the_debt_paid` except the repetitions which are grouped and a block for the month of the `the_debt_paid`. I have tried this but I got stuck:

```
SELECT the_debt_id, the_debt_due, the_debt_paid,
count(the_debt_paid) the_debt_paid_count,
CAST(CONCAT(EXTRACT(month from the_debt_paid), 
     EXTRACT('year' from the_debt_paid)) AS INTEGER) the_debt_paid_month
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY the_debt_id
```

The expected output is:

```
the_debt_id    the_debt_due      the_debt_paid    the_debt_paid_count the_debt_paid_month
LMUS01         2020-08-02        2020-05-18       4                   202005
LMUS01         2020-07-02        2020-05-18       4                   202005
LMUS01         2020-06-02        2020-05-18       4                   202005
LMUS01         2020-05-02        2020-04-28       3                   202004
LMUS01         2020-04-02        2020-04-01       3                   202004
LMUS01         2020-03-02        2020-03-02       2                   202003
LMUS01         2020-02-02        2020-01-31       1                   202001
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by date_trunc('month', the_debt_paid)) as the_debt_paid_count
from my_table t;
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, it worked fine!, just a question, can I then order the column in `desc`? Thank you!

Comment: @Manu . . . Yes.  The order of the rows in the result set is independent of the ordering in the window function.